# Iterating through individual cells of a gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am having a gridview, each cell of which contains a textview. I want to change the text of individual textviews in the gridview on click of a button. Once the text of a particular textview has been changed, i want to move to next cell in the gridview. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

set this property to your textview `android:nextFocusRight` in xml

Comment: with that fiend you just set what the focus will be if the user scrolls right with the d-pad or navigation keys. its like on the pc when you have a button and if you press the right arrow which button will be highlighted next.

Answer (score 0):

well your list view has an adapter. to populate your adapter you are using some sort of an array( of strings, objects etc..) so you need a variable that will track the position of the view in the grid starting from 0 and incrementing with each button click. on the button click before you increment the position you need to change the text of the items array for the adapter on the relevant position and call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter. that's it.